# Infinite loop value

Tags: java

What initial values of x would make the loop infinite? I was told the answer is 123, but I don't understand how. Can somebody explain this?

```
do 
{
   x = x - 3;
}  while (x < 120);
```

Comment: 123 is not the answer.

Comment: A negative value will cause it to loop for a long time, but ultimately the negative number will "underflow" to a positive number and the loop will stop.

Comment: This loop is either "infinite" or single-use, since `x` is decremented and the `while` condition uses LESS-THAN (`<`).

Comment: What happens to X every time around the loop? If the while condition is to be true first time through, how big could x be before that?

Comment: What type is x? Is `-DOUBLE.MAX_VALUE` = `-DOUBLE.MAX_VALUE -3`?

Comment: (there is no value of x that would make the loop infinite.)

Comment: If the value is 122 or smaller, it will be < 120 when the loop test occurs and will continue to decrement.  It will become negative, loop for a long time, and then "underflow" to a large positive number and stop.  Note that if `x` is declared as `long` the "long time" would be pretty close to infinity but not quite.

Comment: If `x` is supposed to be less than 120, set `x` to 119 and then solve. So you'd get `119 = x - 3; x = 122`. But if you want an "infinite" loop use `while (true)`, because as @HotLicks and @njzk2 said, you can't have an infinite while loop using integer values.

Comment: Are `+inf` and `-inf` available in Java?  It seems like it could loop infinitely for at least one of those if `x` is a `double` type...

Comment: Yep, if `x` is not an integer type then most of the above is "inoperative".

Comment: Does that value not have to be less than 120 to start off for it to work? Also, what do you guys mean by "underflow"?

Comment: @user3491684 - What happens if you subtract 1 from the maximum negative value for `int`?

Comment: @Paul No it couldn't, I don't see `x = x.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(3))` but standard fare operators here.

Comment: @jdphenix, correct (I normally do Scala, and that does things like + for big integers properly)

Comment: Don't need +inf or -inf to make it loop forever if the type of x is double.  Assuming x starts out less than 120, it eventually will reach a steady state when the magnitude of x becomes so great that `x-3==x`.

Comment: Data type matters a lot here.  It could loop for quite a while if the type of x is `long`.  I'll be done in a wink of an eye if the type of x is `char`.

Comment: @Paul Oh yeah, methods with `+` as a name... mmm... love it.

Answer (score 1):

No value would cause the loop to be an infinite loop. In java, integral primitive values underflow to a positive number, and thus this loop would eventually end.

As an example:

```
int x = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

do {
    x = x - 3; 
    System.out.println(x);
} while (x < 120);
```

will output:

```
2147483645
```

Answer (score 1):

To understand this further, a 32 bit integer value for decimal 122 is

```
00000000000000000000000001111010
```

If you decrement that you eventually get to zero:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000
```

And decrement 1 more time and get to -1:

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
```

Decrement again and get -2:

```
11111111111111111111111111111110
```

Decrement a whole bunch of times and eventually get to the maximum negative number:

```
10000000000000000000000000000000
```

Decrement once more and you get the maximum positive number:

```
01111111111111111111111111111111
```